# Could they have saved the ancient found in the ice

Tags: stargate

In Stargate SG1 they discover a woman frozen in ice where the second stargate was discovered. This is in season 6 episode 4 btw. In the episode, they find out that she may be millions of years old and could possibly be an Ancient. Later she dies with a disease. Once they got back to the base, why not put her in the sarcophagus? In the last season, they talk about taking it although it was under heavy guard by the Jafa. I'm sure it was worth the risk to retrieve it, because of what they could have learned and what she could have taught them!

Or why not implant her with a symbiote from the Tokra or Chulak?

Just seems like another thing the show decided to cut out.

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry,what I'm asking is could SG1 not have did more to save the women that they found in the ice near the stargate?

Comment: So a list of ways in which they could have saved her and an explanation why they didn't or couldn't have done so?

Comment: Yeah basically what I'm asking is could they have saved her, if so why didn't they? It seemed like they did have other options to try and save her, but the show just killed her off....

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MonsterOfTheWeek

Comment: SG-1 Spoilers. Ayiana (who is referenced as Cyla Urbanus) had the Ori virus as also mentioned in the Fandom Wiki. Human technology wasn't able to cure that; in fact even only with the help of Ancients descending it was possible.